# InteliJ 2018.1 - Syntax highlighting for Scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I just downloaded new version of InteliJ Ultimate 2018.1 (build - 181.4203.550) and imported settings from 2017 version but do not have syntax highlighting nor can run Scala code now (I could this morning in InteliJ Ultimate version 2017).

I verified that have Scala module (Version: 2017.3.11.1) installed.

.java files seems to be fine.

What can be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the Scala plugin installed and enabled?

Comment: You have an old version of the plugin installed. You need to uninstall it and install the new version from the plugin repository.

Comment: The new version of IDEA doesn't install the upgraded Scala plugin. You need to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, installed new Scala plugin and now all works..

Comment: @yole, just as a comment: as far as I remember, when I upgraded IntelliJ Idea Community Edition 2017.3 -> 2018.1 I had not to uninstall and install again the Scala plugin, just go to "Help -> Check for updates"